# Create a nested map from multiple map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a few hash map as follows. I want to merge these map to a single nested map.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Capacity> capacityMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        capacityMap1.put("BMW", new Capacity(10.0, 0.0));
        capacityMap1.put("Audi", new Capacity(20.0, 10.0));
        capacityMap1.put("Toyota", new Capacity(50.0, 0.0));


        HashMap<String, Capacity> capacityMap2 = new HashMap<>();
        capacityMap1.put("BMW", new Capacity(0.0, 10.0));
        capacityMap1.put("Audi", new Capacity(80.0, 0.0));
        capacityMap1.put("Toyota", new Capacity(90.0, 0.0));

        HashMap<String, Capacity> capacityMap3 = new HashMap<>();
        capacityMap1.put("BMW", new Capacity(30.0, 0.0));

        HashMap<String, Capacity> capacityMap4 = new HashMap<>();
        capacityMap1.put("Audi", new Capacity(80.0, 0.0));
        capacityMap1.put("Toyota", new Capacity(90.0, 10.0));
    }

    enum UsageConsumed {
        Inbound,
        OutBound,
    }

    static class Capacity {
        double inBoundCapacity;
        double outBoundcapacit;

        public Capacity(double inBoundCapacity, double outBoundcapacit) {
            this.inBoundCapacity = inBoundCapacity;
            this.outBoundcapacit = outBoundcapacit;
        }
    }

}
```

I want to create a nested map list HashMap<String, Hashmap<UsageConsumed, doble>> where the key will be the key of the above map. If the key is not present then we create a new hashmap with value of the capacity. If the key is already there then we want to add the value to the existing one. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
public static Map<String, HashMap<UsageConsumed, Double>> buildNestedMap(HashMap<String, Capacity>... maps) {

    Map<String, HashMap<UsageConsumed, Double>> result = Stream.of(maps)
            // get a stream of all the map entries
            .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    // create the value for a single entry
                    entry -> {
                        HashMap<UsageConsumed, Double> usageConsumedMap = new HashMap<>();
                        usageConsumedMap.put(UsageConsumed.Inbound, entry.getValue().inBoundCapacity);
                        usageConsumedMap.put(UsageConsumed.OutBound, entry.getValue().outBoundcapacit);
                        return usageConsumedMap;
                    },
                    // merge the values between entries with the same key
                    (a, b) -> {
                        a.merge(UsageConsumed.Inbound, b.get(UsageConsumed.Inbound), Double::sum);
                        a.merge(UsageConsumed.OutBound, b.get(UsageConsumed.OutBound), Double::sum);
                        return a;
                    }
                    ));

    return result;
}
```

Tested with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Capacity> capacityMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    capacityMap1.put("BMW", new Capacity(10.0, 0.0));
    capacityMap1.put("Audi", new Capacity(20.0, 10.0));
    capacityMap1.put("Toyota", new Capacity(50.0, 0.0));
    
    HashMap<String, Capacity> capacityMap2 = new HashMap<>();
    capacityMap2.put("BMW", new Capacity(0.0, 10.0));
    capacityMap2.put("Audi", new Capacity(80.0, 0.0));
    capacityMap2.put("Toyota", new Capacity(90.0, 0.0));

    HashMap<String, Capacity> capacityMap3 = new HashMap<>();
    capacityMap3.put("BMW", new Capacity(30.0, 0.0));

    HashMap<String, Capacity> capacityMap4 = new HashMap<>();
    capacityMap4.put("Audi", new Capacity(80.0, 0.0));
    capacityMap4.put("Toyota", new Capacity(90.0, 10.0));

    Map<String, HashMap<UsageConsumed, Double>> result = buildNestedMap(capacityMap1, capacityMap2, capacityMap3, capacityMap4);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The output is:

```
{Toyota={Inbound=230.0, OutBound=10.0}, Audi={Inbound=180.0, OutBound=10.0}, BMW={Inbound=40.0, OutBound=10.0}}
```